# last observed date

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I need to create a table of the number of cases on the last observed date for each country and print out the country name and the number of cases for the top 5 countries with the highest number of cases.

This is an example of what the data looks like:

```
    Country       Date Confirmed Recovered Deaths
1   Algeria 2020-01-22         0         0      0
2   Algeria 2020-01-23         0         0      0
3   Algeria 2020-01-24         0         0      0
4   Algeria 2020-01-25         0         0      0
5   Algeria 2020-01-26         0         0      0
6   Algeria 2020-01-27         0         0      0
7   Algeria 2020-01-28         0         0      0
8   Algeria 2020-01-29         0         0      0

(There are other countries as well)
```

Update:

So I used this to get the dates and confirmed cases in order, but I'm still struggling to only print out the top 5 countries:

```
by_country_top5 = Africa_covid %>% 
mutate(Date=as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>% 
group_by(Country) %>% 
arrange(desc(Date),desc(Confirmed)) %>%
select(Country,Date,Confirmed)
by_country_top5
```

Answer (score 0):

if your dataframe is `df` and your country column is `country`, cases is called `cases`
and the date column is called `date` :

```
library(dplyr)
 topDates = df$countries %>% 
             unique %>% 
               lapply(function(x){
                 df$date[df$countries == x,] %>% which.max
               }) %>% unlist 

Top5 = df[topDates,] %>% arrange(-date)
Top5
```

Answer (score 0):

After you sort and groupby, you can use `slice` to take the first n rows for each group, for example:

```
set.seed(111)
library(dplyr)
Africa_covid = data.frame(
Country=sample(letters[1:5],100,replace=TRUE),
Date = sample(1:5,100,replace=TRUE),
Confirmed = sample(20,100,replace=TRUE),
Recovered_Deaths = sample(5,100,replace=TRUE)
)

by_country_top5 = Africa_covid %>% 
group_by(Country) %>% 
arrange(desc(Date),desc(Confirmed)) %>%
slice(1:5) %>% 
select(Country,Date,Confirmed)
```